# Javascript код отображается в хроме

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

Оторбражается код  javascript в хроме. В чем причина? При этом он запускается и работает нормально.

Comment: без примера не сказать, кроме того что такого не бывает, если специально не делать.

Comment: Я только учусь читать мысли… но предполагаю, что где-то ошибка ) … в синтаксисе, в коде или еще в чем.

Comment: вот [если бы я хотел это сделать специально](http://jsbin.com/EjiliLU/1/) или [так](http://jsbin.com/EjiliLU/2/edit)

Comment: В html коде ошибок нету, в javascript не выдается ошибок тоже

Comment: скриншот в этом случае не годится.

Comment: вот видимо ваш случай http://jsfiddle.net/H8LXK/

Answer (score 1):

[and  tags are displayed physically on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182211/style-and-script-tags-are-displayed-physically-on-page)

Вот, там стоит display:inline-block у меня к тэгу скрипта. Первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь.

Comment: То есть всё решилось? Кто вообще задает стили к тегам срипта?)